# Which weapon is most effective with the Assault Shield ability?

Tags: the-division

So the Assault Shield ability modifier is described as the following,

> Equips a shield that grants the user's sidearm increased damage,
>   knockback, increased accuracy, and faster reload speed.

Which side arms will gain the most benefit from these bonuses?

Thinking mainly about comparing a shotgun, large magazine pistol and a slow firing small magazine pistol. Better damage would mean that rate of fire is most relevant? But a bigger hit from, say, a Magnum might prove more effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience of running the Assault Shield, I've found larger clips to be more beneficial, more from the stand point of getting more rounds onto the target. More hits means more knockback, which allows you to better control targets you're advancing on using the sheild.

It also gives you an advantage against targets trying to flank your shield. I'd recommend a Damascus, which you can craft from the blueprint recieved from finishing the game, as it has a chance to cause bleed, giving the sidearm a bit of extra punch when using the shield.

Comment: Do note that the Damascus has since been updated.  It now has the **Quickdraw** talent: +20% damage for two seconds, then -20% damage after.  Since you can't swap weapons with a shield out (have to put it away/sprint), most of the time it'll have -20% damage